# How to center a iframe tag in react using tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, youtube-iframe-api, react-video

I want my iframe tag to be displayed at the center of the page but its aligned to the left. The iframe is inside a div tag on which I have tried applying flex items-center and flex justify-content , but nothing workds. here is the code :-

```
 <div className="flex items-center" >
      
      <iframe width="600" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RB1uDVnhVq0?si=d0DlD-AjqmaPlnEF" title="YouTube video player" frameBorder="40% " allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen></iframe>
    
    </div>.
```

Please tell me how to center this iframe.

I have tried applying flex items-center and flex justify-content on the div tag. I wanted to use align attribute in iframe tag but its showing there is no such property.
its running a youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify-center` to the classname of div.

```
<div class="flex items-center justify-center">
  <iframe
    width="600"
    height="400"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RB1uDVnhVq0?si=d0DlD-AjqmaPlnEF"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="40% "
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

Check this out - [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/github/codesandbox-app/static-template/tree/master/?file=%2Findex.html%3A11%2C47)